# Is there an alternative to condensed milk?

Tags: substitutions, milk, condensed-milk

In Denmark we don't have condensed milk in our regular stores and I've actually only seen it in an UK-import store a few years ago. Is there an alternative to it or can you craft it with regular cooking equipment?

Comment: Is that sweetened condensed milk or evaporated milk?  If one is talking about condensed they usually mean the sweetened stuff, but occasionally they mean evaporated instead.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, the recipes I've been looking at only says condensed, like in a toffee topping on a pie.

Comment: If you're making something sweet it's almost always sweetened condensed.

Comment: SuperBrugsen which must be considered a regular store carries Nestles condensed milk. However you may need to ask for where they put it - in my local SuperBrugsen it sits on the shelve with turkish goods.

Comment: I've seen both SuperBest and SuperBrugsen carry condensed milk - if your local store does not carry it, ask if they can order it home for you.

Comment: Seems like it's becoming quite available in danish stores these days, I guess it's after people started spreading out into icecream and toffee recipes.

Comment: Along with turkish, you might try the East Asia food section as it is used to make http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_iced_coffee

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To make sweetened condensed milk:

> The best make-your-own version is to
>   mix 1 cup of evaporated milk with
>   1-1/4 cups of sugar in a saucepan,
>   heat and stir until the sugar is
>   completely dissolved, and let cool.
>
> If you don't have evaporated milk on
>   hand either, you can make your own by
>   slowly simmering any quantity of milk
>   in a pan until it reduced by 60%, and
>   then adding the sugar.

Source: http://www.ochef.com/125.htm

Another recipe that sounds like a lot more work and uses powdered milk: http://www.ehow.com/how_4903555_make-condensed-milk.html

Comment: Evaporated milk is...? (unknowing dane here :))

Comment: Evaporated milk is milk that has had some of it's water content removed (by evaporation or cooking it off, slowly).

Comment: You could also make condensed milk from regular whole milk. Just cook down the milk (whilst stirring constantly to stop the milk sticking and burning) in a heavy bottomed pot until it loses about a quarter / a third of its volume, then add the sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Mix 2 1/4 cups of blue milk and 1/2 cup of sugar. Mix.

Comment: What is blue milk?  Googling provides no reasonable hits.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Wild guess: 2% milk, since I think it's the one most commonly sold with a blue label?

Comment: @Jefromi I had no idea there was a convention for that--but it would be regional, if it exists, I think...

Comment: My guess is it's regional. Where I live [evaporated milk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporated_milk) is usually labelled in blue. But [googling it with its English name](https://www.google.es/search?q=evaporated+milk&tbm=isch) shows many cans with red labels.

Comment: In the UK, blue-topped milk is full-fat. I assume that's what gemma means, as to the best of my knowledge most condensed milk is made from raw unskimmed milk. For completeness: green is semi-skimmed ("2%"), and red is skimmed.

Answer (score 0):

One recipe of mine has peanut butter as a substitute for sweetened condensed milk but I don't think this is appropriate for all recipes. It is convenient, as I always have some peanut butter in the pantry.

Comment: I would guess that it is a very small subset of recipes which will work with this kind of substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Condensed milk and evaporated milk have the same consistency (almost) simply because both of them are made by the same process of evaporating 60% of the water content but the similarity ends there. Because sweet condensed milk contains added sugar you cannot [substitute condensed milk](http://www.chihollandia.com/can-hollandia-evap-milk-be-a-substitute-for-condensed-milk/) for evaporated milk.
Evaporated milk is not as sweet as condensed milk.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.cooks.com/rec/view/0,183,151170-244199,00.html) has some good to amazing reviews.

> **Sweetened condensed milk substitute**
>
> - 2 eggs
> - 1 c. brown sugar
> - 1 tsp. vanilla
> - 2 tbsp. flour
> - 1/2 tsp. baking powder
> - 1/4 tsp. salt
>
> Mix all ingredients and use as a substitute for sweetened condensed
>   milk in recipes for pies, bars and desserts.

Comment: Sweetened condensed milk really is just milk with a bunch of sugar and less water. This is going to be way different - different flavor from the salt, vanilla, and brown sugar, different thickening and binding properties from the eggs and flour, and maybe even a bit of leavening from the baking powder.

Comment: This recipe has some great qualitys, and it is made from basic kitchen ingredents! This recipe was also a help to my sister who was making cheescake, and we didn't happen to have some spare condensed milk around the kitchen! Thank you, " Seasoned Advice"!

Comment: This is nasty and has no similarity at all to the product it supposedly is a substitute for.... and has raw eggs, where condensed milk is often used without further cooking in refrigerator pies, for example.